# path in shebang

Tags: bash

I have /bin/bash (3.2) and /usr/local/bin/bash (4.0) on my computer. In the $PATH environment variable, bash 4.0 is prior to bash 3.2.

in my bash script shebang, I don't like to explicitly use:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

I'd like to find bash based on $PATH priority. How to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can always try

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```